# How to install the drivers for a Realtek wireless usb adapter (on Debian Buster OS)?

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers

I bought a Realtek ac1200 wireless usb 3 adapter from amazon, and I am currently trying to get it setup on my computer. My computer was previously Windows XP (but I converted it to a Debian Buster OS). The usb adapter came with a driver installer mini-disc, which contains a Linux, Mac, and Windows install folders. I copied the Linux folder to my desktop and there are two sub-folders within that one: RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux and RTL8812BU_WiFi_linux. I have no clue which one I am supposed to use, but nevertheless, I tried running the install.sh that is in each folder respectively. To my dismay, both have compile errors when I run (specifically warnings and errors being shown for C Header files that the install.sh is trying to run). Since I couldn't get the actual install.sh's to work that came with the adapter, I searched the internet trying to find if I could download the drivers somewhere else, but I couldn't get any of them to work. Does anyone know how to get the appropriate drivers installed for my usb adapter so my computer can use the adapter?

The errors I get when running the install.sh is as follows:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-9-686-pae'


CC [M]  /home/caleb/Desktop/Linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/driver/rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.5.3_24795.20171031_COEX20170310-1212/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /home/caleb/Desktop/Linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/driver/rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.5.3_24795.20171031_COEX20170310-1212/include/osdep_service.h:47,
                 from /home/caleb/Desktop/Linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/driver/rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.5.3_24795.20171031_COEX20170310-1212/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /home/caleb/Desktop/Linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/driver/rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.5.3_24795.20171031_COEX20170310-1212/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/home/caleb/Desktop/Linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/driver/rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.5.3_24795.20171031_COEX20170310-1212/include/osdep_service_linux.h: In function ‘_init_timer’:
/home/caleb/Desktop/Linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/driver/rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.5.3_24795.20171031_COEX20170310-1212/include/osdep_service_linux.h:295:8: error: ‘_timer’ {aka ‘struct timer_list’} has no member named ‘data’
  ptimer->data = (unsigned long)cntx;
        ^~
/home/caleb/Desktop/Linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/driver/rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.5.3_24795.20171031_COEX20170310-1212/include/osdep_service_linux.h:296:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’; did you mean ‘_init_timer’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  init_timer(ptimer);
  ^~~~~~~~~~
  _init_timer
In file included from /home/caleb/Desktop/Linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/driver/rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.5.3_24795.20171031_COEX20170310-1212/include/drv_types.h:35,
                 from /home/caleb/Desktop/Linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/driver/rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.5.3_24795.20171031_COEX20170310-1212/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/home/caleb/Desktop/Linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/driver/rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.5.3_24795.20171031_COEX20170310-1212/include/wifi.h: At top level:
/home/caleb/Desktop/Linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/driver/rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.5.3_24795.20171031_COEX20170310-1212/include/wifi.h:1019: warning: "IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF" redefined
 #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF 0x40
 
In file included from /home/caleb/Desktop/Linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/driver/rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.5.3_24795.20171031_COEX20170310-1212/include/osdep_service_linux.h:86,
                 from /home/caleb/Desktop/Linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/driver/rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.5.3_24795.20171031_COEX20170310-1212/include/osdep_service.h:47,
                 from /home/caleb/Desktop/Linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/driver/rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.5.3_24795.20171031_COEX20170310-1212/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /home/caleb/Desktop/Linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/driver/rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.5.3_24795.20171031_COEX20170310-1212/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-9-common/include/linux/ieee80211.h:1442: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF  0x100
 
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[4]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-9-common/scripts/Makefile.build:309: /home/caleb/Desktop/Linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/driver/rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.5.3_24795.20171031_COEX20170310-1212/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-9-common/Makefile:1537: _module_/home/caleb/Desktop/Linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux/driver/rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.5.3_24795.20171031_COEX20170310-1212] Error 2
make[2]: *** [Makefile:146: sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:8: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-9-686-pae'
make: *** [Makefile:1893: modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################
```

Comment: If you want to try the rtl88x2bu driver, I've had great with this one: https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to [ajgringo6019](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/363044/ajgringo619) for their comment with the link to https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu! I cloned that git hub repository and followed the "DKMS Installation" guide on their github page and it worked perfectly!

Comment: Consider adding the steps from the DKMS installation guide to your answer to add value to it.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the answer above.  Here is the code from the repo on how to run the "DKMS Installation"

I can confirm this has worked very well (180MBS download, 280+ upload) on my

- Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-42-generic
- Architecture: x86-64

```bsh
git clone https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu
cd rtl88x2bu/
VER=$(sed -n 's/\PACKAGE_VERSION="\(.*\)"/\1/p' dkms.conf)
sudo rsync -rvhP ./ /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-${VER}
sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms build -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms install -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

Comment: Hi, to unix SE welcome! Answers are not in a static ordering, so referring other answer as "the answer above" is inappropriate. You may want to provide a link to the other answer. Better would be to conclude the main idea of that answer, so to save the trip of readers, and in case that other answer may change or disappear itself.